# React-virtualized - is it possible to use custom column?

Tags: react-virtualized

I am using react-virtualized to render my table. Is it possible at all to replace the default Column component with a custom one? I keep getting this error 
`Failed prop type: Table only accepts children of type Column`

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course,you can do that by using  **cellRenderer** prop in Column  which is callback function and it will give you bunch of parameters and you need return the custom component that will render in cell

```
<Column key={column.dataKey + column.label + index} dataKey={column.dataKey}
        cellRenderer={
            ({ cellData, rowIndex, dataKey }) => (
                <CheckBox
                  cellData={cellData}
                  changeCheckBox={changeCheckBoxHandler.bind(
                    this,
                    rowIndex,
                    dataKey
                  )}
                />
              )
            }/>
```

you  can find out in detail here. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md#cellrenderer

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do this? You have to use the `Column` component to define every column, and then you can render whatever you want inside each `Column`.

Comment: because you would like to reuse the column component for example?